# Is this the correct way to use way :dependent => :destroy in my RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This is how my RoR app is setup

note.rb

```
belongs_to :user 
has_many :note_categories
has_many :categories, :through => :note_categories
```

category.rb

```
has_many :note_categories
has_many :notes, :through => :note_categories
```

I want to make it so that when a user deletes a note, the corresponding entry in the note_categories table is deleted as well. Do I use :dependent => :destroy to do that?

Also, if I wanted to make it so that if a user deletes a note, and that means that there are no more notes with the category it had, the category itself was deleted, how would I do that? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make it so that when a user
>   deletes a note, the corresponding
>   entry in the note_categories table is
>   deleted as well. Do I use :dependent
>   => :destroy to do that?

Yes, that's correct.

> Also, if I wanted to make it so that
>   if a user deletes a note, and that
>   means that there are no more notes
>   with the category it had, the category
>   itself was deleted, how would I do
>   that?

You use an after_destroy callback.

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :note_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :note_categories      
end 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :note_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :notes, :through => :note_categories
end

class NoteCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :category
  after_destroy { category.destroy  if category.notes.empty? }
end
```